# why webpage is not rendering code

Tags: python, flask

for some reason - I am not getting any errors, but the variables are coming up blank

---

Hello, test!

the local date and time is .

that was .

---

*website.py*

```
from flask_moment import Moment
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
moment = Moment(app)

@app.route('/index')
def index():
        return render_template('index.html', current_time=datetime.utcnow())
```

*templates/index.html*

```
<h3>Hello, test!</h3>

<p>the local date and time is {{ moment(current_time).format('LLL') }}.</p>
<p>that was {{ moment(current_time).fromNow(refresh=True) }}.</p>
```

Comment: _but the page is coming up as a blank_ Do you mean the **page** is blank, or those two variables are blank?

Comment: Those 2 variables are blank. Sorry, edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [flask_moment Readme](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-Moment), Step 1. says you need to initialize the extension by calling it with your flask app like so:

```
from flask_moment import Moment
from datetime import datetime

# initialize you flask app
app = Flask(__name__)
# initialize the moment extension
Moment(app)

@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', current_time=datetime.utcnow())
```

Then Step 2. is including this in your template:

```
<head>
    {{ moment.include_jquery() }}
    {{ moment.include_moment() }}
</head>
```

This is why the template is rendering blank; the moment function is not recognized by the templating module.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include that. I have edited the above.

Comment: Do you also have to pass `moment` into the template context, just as you are doing with `current_time`?

Comment: I do not believe so, as I would rather pass the datetime in raw format and then handle it in my template. I should be able to do that, right?